# Ignore blanks with countif

Tags: excel, countif

Good morning.

I am trying (without success!) to exclude blanks from the following formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(‘Deliveries’!A1:A114,{“Yes”;"Probably”}))/COUNTA(‘Deliveries’!A1:A114)
```

Currently, this formula tells me how many entries there are for Yes and Probably in column A, in a percentage, so I’d like to exclude it from counting blank cells ie. **I only want a percentage of the cells that are completed, NOT a percentage of the entire column.**

Can anyone help please?  I’ve tried adding “*” and “<>” but it returns an error.....

Thank you in advance for any advice received.

Comment: [No noises in post please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Doesn't `counta` count nonempty cells by default?

Comment: Noise?  **I'll** make some noise.  **Welcome to Stack Overflow!** A good first step when troubleshooting a formula is to break is down into the smallest pieces possible, to help determine exactly which part is causing the problem, and Googling that function or section specifically, to see if it's supposed to act how you expect it to. For example, try running the `COUNTA` and the `COUNTIF` parts separately, read the documentation for whichever is the problem, and if you still can't figure it out, you can always [edit] your question.

Comment: ...Including a sample of the data or a screenshot of what you're working with, can help others help you as well.  See "[mcve]" as well as "[ask]" and great tips [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).   ...Have a ***fantastic*** day, and thank **you** for joining!       ♫  ‎

Comment: @user202729: Yes, but it is unclear what @ToF means to be a blank cell. A cell containing a empty string `=""` is **not** a blank cell and `COUNTA` will count it.

Answer (score 1):

if i have understood your question correctly then this the formula you are looking for

`=(COUNTIF(A4:A26,"Yes")+COUNTIF(A4:A26,"Probably"))/COUNTA(A4:A26)`

Formula for excluding not applicable

`=(COUNTIF(A4:A26,"Yes")+COUNTIF(A4:A26,"Probably"))/(COUNTA(A4:A26)-COUNTIF(A4:A26,"N/A"))`

**Change the range accordingly

Comment: Thank you Praveen, that actually makes perfect sense :)  Further to this, though, is there a way to also exclude other responses (can I exclude "Not applicable"?)

Comment: @ToF not sure I can give a check on that\